# jquery: changing input val with jquery doesn't affect the input interceptor

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys!

Let's assume the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var data = 'clients=&categories=&keywords=&limit='+limit;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_list',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
      $('.list').html(data);
      $('.thumb').click(function() {
    var idz = 'id='+$(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_work',
      data: idz,
      success: function (data) {
        $('.client').click(function() {
          $('#clients').val($('.client').text());
        });
      }
    });
      });
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function(){
    var clients = $('#clients').val(),
    data = 'clients='+clients;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_list',
      data: data,
      success: function (data) { $('.list').html(data);
    $('.thumb').click(function() {
      var idz = 'id='+$(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_work',
        data: idz,
        success: function (data) {
          $('.work').hide().html(data).slideToggle('slow');
        }
      });
    });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And somewhere on the page there is an input and some images:

```
      <div class="work"></div>
      <input type="text" id="clients" name="clients">
      <div class="list">Some thumbnails that call index.php?ind=work&op=get_work</div>
```

Now, when I type anything in the input, the jquery intercepts it on change and gets the information from get_list function. It works perfectly with .keyup(), .change(), .on('change') and .on('input').

But when I press the client name (span with class="client"), the input #clients is changed, but the list is not loaded.

I have a feeling I miss something soooo basic :))

Thanks for hints!

Comment: please share a fiddle.

Comment: you have to manually fire change event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are changing the value of a TextBox programatically then change event doesn't fire.

to fire the event u have  manually fire the event by using **change()**

Change this code

```
 $('.client').click(function () {
     $('#clients').val($('.client').text());
 });
```

To

```
 $('.client').click(function () {
     $('#clients').val($('.client').text());
     $('#clients').change();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `<span class=client>` in your code, but assuming it's there, your error is that setting the value of an `<input>` element does not trigger any events, not even "input" or "change". Those only get triggered by actual user actions. Try triggering the event directly, in your click handler:

```
$('.client').click(function() {
  $('#clients').val($('.client').text());
  $('#clients').trigger('change'); // or whatever event you are listening for
});
```

Or, more briefly:

```
$('.client').click(function() {
  $('#clients').val($('.client').text()).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you register the span event when the input change ... so the text change when it click on the span but it's not registred.

You register the span click after the click happen ... you can verify this by click once on the span, whait and click again.

The best thing is to register all events on the load and use a boolean if you whant to prevent an event action.

Like :

```
var preventaction = true;
$("#btn1").click(function(){
If (! preventaction) { dostuf(); }
});
```